# cakePHP conditions added in beforeFind function has no effect on paginate

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to filter the results of a query. A user can only see companies that have the same company_group_id as his, so I tought of adding that condition in the beforeFind function of my model.

```
function beforeFind($queryData) {
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
    $user = CakeSession::read('Auth.User');
    $queryData['conditions']['Company.company_group_id'] = $user['company_group_id'];
    parent::beforeFind($queryData);
}
```

I can see this condition appear when I pr() my $queryData

```
Array
(
[conditions] => Array
    (
        [Company.company_group_id] => 2
    )

)
```

Unfortunately, the resulting query when I call my paginate ignores this condition

```
SELECT `Company`.`id`, ... WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Company`.`id` ORDER BY `Company`.`name` asc LIMIT 10
```

Am I doing this correctly? Or is there another way to show the correct records to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure the pagination behavior in your controller's action (more about this [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)):

```
//obtaining the company_group_id
$user = CakeSession::read('Auth.User');
$id = $user['company_group_id'];

//setting the pagination conditions (similar to a find())
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Company.company_group_id' => $id),
);

$data = $this->paginate('Company');
$this->set('data', $data);
```

Comment: I already have many seach conditions that I dynamically add to my paginate when the user applies filters but the idea of having the company_group_id in the model is because I want this condition on every query instead of adding it manually in every controller action. Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: @DominicHorbas You can always merge this condition (`array('Company.company_group_id' => $id)` with the dynamic search conditions you're getting from your users using `array_merge()` ?

Comment: Well I guess I don't have any choice. Thank you!